# Read non empty multiple files in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-1.5

I use `sc.textFile()` to read multiple files from S3 in Spark. But, the input S3 path also has a few empty files that give NullPointerException. Is there a way that I can ignore these files?

```
val inputFile = sc.textfile("s3n://mypath/*file")
val inputRDD = inputFile.map(_.split(",")).map(line => {
               //processing 
               })
```

Edit: Adding stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 128 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 128.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 128, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(NativeS3FileSystem.java:130)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:209)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:47)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:216)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:388)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:894)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:894)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the files then?